# Upgrade Ubuntu Server 20.04.5 LTS/22.04.1 LTS - appears "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading"

Tags: apt, server, upgrade, updates

Having VirtualBox with Ubuntu Server based on:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

and

```
neofetch --off
------------------------
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS x86_64
Host: VirtualBox 1.2
Kernel: 5.4.0-125-generic
Uptime: 17 mins
Packages: 1272 (dpkg), 5 (snap)
Shell: bash 5.0.17
Resolution: preferred
Terminal: /dev/pts/0
CPU: Intel i5-3230M (2) @ 2.594GHz
GPU: 00:02.0 VMware SVGA II Adapter
Memory: 236MiB / 3883MiB
```

Based in these two valuable tutorials:

- [Upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 LTS using command line](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04-lts-using-command-line/)
- [How to Upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-22-04/)

I did do the following steps:

```
sudo apt-mark showhold             # Returns nothing
sudo apt-mark unhold <packagename> # Not necessary as above returned nothing
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 Calculating upgrade... Done
 The following packages have been kept back:
   mysql-client mysql-server
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

sudo reboot

sudo apt full-upgrade
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 Calculating upgrade... Done
 The following packages have been kept back:
   mysql-client mysql-server
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

sudo apt --purge autoremove
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

sudo apt install update-manager-core # It to install 'do-release-upgrade'

sudo do-release-upgrade -c
 Checking for a new Ubuntu release
 New release '22.04.1 LTS' available.
 Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

sudo do-release-upgrade # <---- final step
 Checking for a new Ubuntu release
 Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

I did do the process shown above just in case twice and always appears the message:

```
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading
```

How to resolve this scenario?

**Note** Just in case, I am doing this process through `ssh` in the same LAN.

**Note** in other Virtual Machine, right now the upgrade process is working, but it for Ubuntu server 18 to 20 ... therefore it seems the steps instructions shared are correct

Comment: Try to `apt install` packages that are held back

Comment: Run `apt-cache policy` on the two packages kept back. Look for version conflicts, wrong sources, phasing, and other common reasons for a package to be kept back.

Comment: Also check for missing sources. Some folks disabled their -updates and/or -security pockets for various reasons. Make sure both are enabled.

Comment: Was uninstalled mysql, now all the upgrade process is going well so far - for the other VM where was upgraded from 18 to 20 - until here all ok - then a 2nd upgrade was accomplished from to 20 to 22 the upgrade went wrong and finally _Kernel Panic_ - and in other 3rd VM for Ubuntu **Desktop** it was upgraded from 20 to 22 in peace - well it is all about experience - and all based through VirtualBox - testing by experimentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same situation in other Virtual Machine.

Therefore according with the following part:

```
 The following packages have been kept back:
   mysql-client mysql-server
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

it appears twice in the original post, and the following line

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded
```

appears a total of three times.

Therefore the `2 not upgraded` was the indicator of the problem.

**Solution**

For this specific situation is mandatory remove `MySQL` - perhaps you have more software with this situation. Then consider to remove them. Of course, remember always do a backup from the beginning.